# Show that $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know how to prove one to one and onto and I define the function $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \to (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ by $\phi([n]) = [n+1]$, but i don't know how to prove $\phi(ab)= \phi(a)\phi(b)$. 
Thanks

Comment: Prove that both are cyclic and then try to prove that two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic.

Comment: Indeed, there's only one abelian group of order $6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\phi([n]) = [n+1]$ does not define a group isomorphism: this would imply
$$
[3] = \phi([2]) = \phi([1] + [1]) = \phi([1]) \phi([1]) = [2][2] = [4] \quad \mbox{in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}^\ast$}
$$ 
which is false. Instead, consider $\phi([n]) = [3^n]$.

Comment: I got it!!!! Thanks A lot!!

Answer (score 1):

hint: $Z/7Z$ is a field thus $(Z/7Z)^*$ is cyclic and its order is 6. You can do it by hand $3, 3^2=9=2$ mod 7, $3^3=6$ mod 7, $3^4=4$ mod 7, $3^5=5$ mod 7, $3^6 =1$mod 7. So the class of 3 is a generator of $(Z/7Z)^*$.

Comment: You also need the existence of a primitive root modulo $7$.  All Fermat tells you is exactly what Lagrange's theorem would tell you for a group of order $6$, namely that the order of the elements divides the order of the group.